# How can I track down the thread that is still working after finishing the test?

Tags: c#, nunit

I am using NUnit with Resharper. When I finish one test, the JetBrain:Resharper process is still working and when I write out its threads, there is still some thread working. Can I track down what kind of thread it is? I am currently using the following code, but it only gives me the thread ID. I need the thread name.

```
Process[] allProcs = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process proc in allProcs)
{
    if (proc.ProcessName.StartsWith("Jet"))
    {
        ProcessThreadCollection myThreads = proc.Threads;
        Console.WriteLine("process: {0},  id: {1}", proc.ProcessName, proc.Id);

        foreach (ProcessThread pt in myThreads)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  thread:  {0}", pt.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("    started: {0}", pt.StartTime.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("    CPU time: {0}", pt.TotalProcessorTime);
            Console.WriteLine("    priority: {0}", pt.BasePriority);
            Console.WriteLine("    thread state: {0}", pt.ThreadState.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Output from code above:

```
process: JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.MSIL,  id: 1884

thread:  3600
started: 27.1.2011 13.26.55
CPU time: 00:00:05.8812377
priority: 8
thread state: Running
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ReSharper test runner process is still there then attach the debugger to it and "break all" to see the currently executing threads.

**Attach Visual Studio debugger to process**

The following shows how to attach the VS debugger to a running process. Choose the ReSharper test runner when choosing which process to attach too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx

**Break All**

Choosing this option will suspend all running threads and allow you to inspect them.

> Menu -> Debug -> Break All

**View Threads**

The "Threads" window gives you a list of all threads for the current process which is being debugged.

> Menu -> Debug -> Windows -> Threads

More detail on the "Threads" window:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15yf86f.aspx

Comment: Can you be more specific how to do it in VS2010?

Comment: @Simon No problem, which areas do you need more detail on e.g. are you comfortable with attaching the debugger to a process?

Comment: @chibacity: I don't know how to attach debugger to process, and what does it mean "break all".

Comment: @Simon No problem, but first, what makes you think that you have an issue with an "NUnit thread"? Details of what you are seeing could make this easier to diagnose.

Comment: I think that there is some thread, maybe not from NUnit or Reshaper, but from my code (some timer, event, thread) who is hanging even if everything is disposed and test is finished. And Resharper process is still in memory.